# Suppress chktex warning about custom capitalized command

Tags: chktex

Sometimes I define capitalized commands, e.g., `\USA`. Using this command at the end of a sentence produces a ChkTeX warning about using intersentence spacing. How can I suppress this warning uniformly for such commands?

Comment: This is clearly a bug. You can open a ticket on https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?group=chktex, the current package maintainer responds actively to new issues there.

Comment: Done, thanks! https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/index.php?60809

Comment: FWIW I released a new version (will take a while to appear on CTAN, TeX Live, etc.) which adds some more customization around this type of scenario.